# How can i make a pause menu in unity which stops a timer in unity 4.6

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, menu

How can i make a pause menu in unity which stops a timer in unity 4.6 ?
Here is the script :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class pauseMenu : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public GUISkin myskin;

private Rect windowRect;
private bool paused = false , waited = true;

private void Start()
{
    windowRect = new Rect(Screen.width / 2 - 100, Screen.height / 2 - 100, 200, 200);
}

private void waiting()
{
    waited = true;
}

private void Update()
{
    if (waited)
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Escape) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.P))
        {
            if (paused)
                paused = false;
            else
                paused = true;

            waited = false;
            Invoke("waiting",0.3f);
        }
}

private void OnGUI()
{
    if (paused)
        windowRect = GUI.Window(0, windowRect, windowFunc, "Pause Menu");
}

private void windowFunc(int id)
{
    if (GUILayout.Button("Resume"))
    {
        paused = false;
    }
    if (GUILayout.Button ("Restart")) 
    {
        Application.LoadLevel("LEVEL 1");
    }
    if (GUILayout.Button("Quit"))
    {
        Application.LoadLevel("Main Menu");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit : After checking your actual project**

**Problem**

You are using two different classes for creating timer, one is "pauseMenu" which you have mentioned in your question and other one is "Timer" which is this one

```
#pragma strict

var timer : float = 10.0;

function Update()
{
    timer -= Time.deltaTime;

    if(timer <= 0)
    {
        timer = 0;
        //DO SOMETHING EPIC!
    }
}


function OnGUI()
{
    GUI.Box(new Rect(1, 2, 70, 30), "Time: " + timer.ToString("0"));
}
```

Now please note first class is written in C# and the other class is in javascript.

**There are two solution to achieve you goal**

**1.**

Using both script together is very tricky, you need to keep your first script in plugin folder, because of unity's execution order and access "time" variable from javascript. or

**2.**

You can delete your javascript "timer" and update your C# class "pauseMenu" with following code.

*************************** New Code ***********************

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class pauseMenu : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public GUISkin myskin;

    private Rect windowRect;
    private bool paused = false , waited = true;
    private float time = 60f;

    private void Start()
    {
        windowRect = new Rect(Screen.width / 2 - 100, Screen.height / 2 - 100, 200, 200);
    }

    private void waiting()
    {
        waited = true;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (waited)
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Escape) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.P))
        {
            if (paused)
                paused = false;
            else
                paused = true;

            waited = false;
            Invoke("waiting",0.3f);
        }
        if(!paused)
            if(time>0)
                time -= Time.deltaTime;
    }

    private void OnGUI()
    {
        if (paused)
            windowRect = GUI.Window(0, windowRect, windowFunc, "Pause Menu");
        GUI.Box(new Rect(1, 2, 70, 30), "Time: " + time.ToString("0"));
    }

    private void windowFunc(int id)
    {
        if (GUILayout.Button("Resume"))
        {
            paused = false;
        }
        if (GUILayout.Button ("Restart")) 
        {
            Application.LoadLevel("LEVEL 1");
        }
        if (GUILayout.Button("Quit"))
        {
            Application.LoadLevel("Main Menu");
        }
    }
}
```

---

------------------------ Previous code -----------------------------

Like this

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class pauseMenu : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public GUISkin myskin;

    private Rect windowRect;
    private bool paused = true , waited = true;
    private float time = 0;

    private void Start()
    {
        windowRect = new Rect(Screen.width / 2 - 100, Screen.height / 2 - 100, 200, 200);
    }

    private void waiting()
    {
        waited = true;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (waited)
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Escape) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.P))
        {
            if (paused)
                paused = false;
            else
                paused = true;

            waited = false;
            Invoke("waiting",0.3f);
        }
        if(paused)time += Time.deltaTime;
        Debug.Log (time);
    }

    private void OnGUI()
    {
        if (paused)
            windowRect = GUI.Window(0, windowRect, windowFunc, "Pause Menu");
    }

    private void windowFunc(int id)
    {
        if (GUILayout.Button("Resume"))
        {
            paused = false;
        }
        if (GUILayout.Button ("Restart")) 
        {
            Application.LoadLevel("LEVEL 1");
        }
        if (GUILayout.Button("Quit"))
        {
            Application.LoadLevel("Main Menu");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It still doesnt work.I could send you my project to fix this bug

Comment: It is a tested and working script but it may not be working in your case anyways send the link of your project file I will look into it.

Comment: I am looking into it, will get back to you asap.

Comment: Neeraj, I have two more questions, how i can make the ball stop when i prees escape and if the timer reaches zero i want to appear a game over scene (I need just the scripts)Thanks a lot.

Comment: sorry bro, I am not much familiar with javascript, but I will suggest you that you should rewrite the above c# class into javascript and make pause variable static, then you can access it in the update function from other classes, and you will be able to stop the ball by simply checking if game is in the pause state.